# How to create a Stream from reading and transforming a file?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper

I'm trying to read a file, decrypt it, and return the data. Because the file is potentially very big, I want to do this in a stream.

I cannot find a good pattern to implement the stream. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
let stream = stream::unfold(decrypted_init_length, |decrypted_length| async move {
    if decrypted_length < start + length {
        let mut encrypted_chunk = vec![0u8; encrypted_block_size];
        match f.read(&mut encrypted_chunk[..]) {
            Ok(size) => {
                if size > 0 {
                    let decrypted = my_decrypt_fn(&encrypted_chunk[..]);
                    let updated_decrypted_length = decrypted_length + decrypted.len();
                    Some((decrypted, updated_decrypted_length))
                } else {
                    None
                }
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error {}", e);
                None
            }
        }
    } else {
        None
    }
});
```

The problem is that `f.read` is not allowed in the above async closure with the following error:

```
89  | |             match f.read(&mut encrypted_chunk[..]) {
    | |                   -
    | |                   |
    | |                   move occurs because `f` has type `std::fs::File`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    | |                   move occurs due to use in generator
```

I don't want to open `f` inside the closure itself. Is there any better way to fix this?  I am OK with using a different crate or trait, or method (i.e. not `stream::unfold`).

Comment: Are you using an asynchronous file type? (e.g. [async-std](https://docs.rs/async-std/*/async_std/fs/struct.File.html) or [tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/*/tokio/fs/struct.File.html)).

Comment: @squiguy No, I am using a regular file type, i.e. `std::fs::File`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution: using `async-stream` crate at [here](https://crates.io/crates/async-stream).

One of the reasons `stream::unfold` did not work for me is that the `async move` closure does not allow access `mut` variables outside, for example the `f` file handle.

Now with `async-stream`, I changed my code to the following, and it works: (note the `yield` added by this crate).

```
use async_stream::try_stream;

<snip>

    try_stream! {
        while decrypted_length < start + length {
            match f.read(&mut encrypted_chunk[..]) {
                Ok(size) => 
                    if size > 0 {
                        println!("read {} bytes", size);
                        let decrypted = my_decrypt_fn(&encrypted_chunk[..size], ..);
                        decrypted_length = decrypted_length + decrypted.len();
                        yield decrypted;
                    } else {
                        break
                    }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Error {}", e);
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

I found that `async-stream` has some limitations that I cannot ignore. I ended up implementing `Stream` directly and no longer using `async-stream`. Now my code looks like this:

```
pub struct DecryptFileStream {
    f: File,
    <other_fields>,
}

impl Stream for DecryptFileStream {
    type Item = io::Result<Vec<u8>>;

    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>,
                  _cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<io::Result<Vec<u8>>>> {
         // read the file `f` of self and business_logic
         // 
         if decrypted.len() > 0 {
             Poll::Ready(Some(Ok(decrypted)))
         } else {
             Poll::Ready(None)
         }
    }
}

//. then use the above stream: 

    let stream = DecryptFileStream::new(...);
    Response::new(Body::wrap_stream(stream))
```

Comment: Where does `Stream` come from? Can you add the imports?

Comment: I think it's from this one https://docs.rs/futures-core/0.3.25/futures_core/stream/trait.Stream.html

Answer (score 0):

`stream::unfold` is only for types that implement `Stream`, which in Rust is used exclusively for asynchronous programming. If you want to do synchronous reading, what you're calling a "stream" is tagged as implementing [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) in Rust. Thus you can call `Read::read()` to read some data off the current position of your `File` (limited by the length of the buffer you pass in), and decrypt that data.

Comment: Although I am using `std::fs::File` to read the chunk, the higher level logic is asynchronous programming. In this case, I am using `hyper` crate and I wanted to create a stream for `hyper` response body.

Comment: So you want to take an encrypted file and apply [`Body::wrap_stream()`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.4/hyper/body/struct.Body.html#method.wrap_stream) to it? In that case you probably want to use `tokio::fs::File` and its `AsyncRead` impl. It would probably help if you clear up your question as Shepmaster suggested, though.

Comment: yes I will use `Body::wrap_stream()` once I got a stream out of the file. I found a good crate to do that now.  Posted details as separated answer.